# How to clear the spaces in phone number in app inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am developing a app in app inventor 2. When i retrieve a phone number(for eg.+************) from the contact's list by using the phone number picker
and setting that phonenumber to a label it appears like (+** ***** *****). I need to clear all the spaces and the phone number should look like(+************). I am not able to do it by using the trim function in text section of app inventor 2. Can any one please suggest me how to clear all the spaces in the phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace all](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/text.html#replaceall) to replace all instances of `" "` (the space character) with `""` (nothing).